# Proxy for event bus - how to resolve IEnumerable<T> during OnActivating event

Tags: c#, autofac

Consider that I've some interfaces like: `IFirstEvent` etc. Now, I can have multiple implementations of `IFirstEvent` interface. I would like to register all implementations in `ContainerBuilder` in order to use dependency injection inside implementations (and other Autofac features). Next, I would like to replace `IFirstEvent` with proxy class (at resolving time) that will call other implementaions (I would like to inject single `IFirstEvent` not `IEnumerable<IFirstEvent>` in order to use it).
I wrote following snippet:

```
var localEventType = typeof(IFirstEvent);
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(this.assemblies)
       .AssignableTo(localEventType)
       .As(localEventType)
       .InstancePerRequest()
       .OnActivating(ctx =>
                     {
                         var allImplementations =
                                  (IEnumerable)
                                  ctx.Context
                                     .Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable<>)
                                       .MakeGenericType(localEventType));

                         var proxy = MultiInterfaceProxy.For(
                                          localEventType, 
                                          allImplementations);
                         ctx.ReplaceInstance(proxy);
                     });
```

Unfortunately, the registration throws error about circular dependency (what is quite obvious - when resolving collection of `IFirstEvent`, every item would be replaced with proxy class).

So, how can I replace instance with proxy and would be able to **find and resolve** all concrete implementations of interface?
I don't want to search assemblies for concrete implementations manually because I need to create instance manually then (I would like to avoid it in order to let autofac manage lifetimescopes). Maybe there is no other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to avoid the circular dependency is to register your implementation using keyed service and then register a delegate as your service :

```
var localEventType = typeof(IFirstEvent);
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(this.assemblies)
      .AssignableTo(localEventType)
      .Keyed(ProxyBuilder.ProxyKey, localEventType)
      .InstancePerRequest(); 

builder.Register(c =>
{
   Type enumerableEventType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(localEventType);
   IEnumerable implementations = (IEnumerable)c.ResolveKeyed(ProxyBuilder.ProxyKey, 
                                                             enumerableEventType);

   var proxy = MultiInterfaceProxy.For(localEventType, 
                                       implementations);

});
```

`ProxyBuilder.ProxyKey` is a constant. ie :

```
public static class ProxyBuilder
{
    public static readonly Object ProxyKey = new Object();
}
```